# Unable to attach Tampermonkey script to specific page

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm creating a simple script to add a tooltip for cards I see on this [page](https://www.ligapokemon.com.br/?view=cards/lista) (you will need an account if you are interested). Even the simple code to show a tooltip is causing errors to the page and making it unusable.
Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var $ = window.jQuery;

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if ( $(".cardtitle") !== 'undefined' ) {
             $(".cardtitle").prop('title', 'What an awesome tooltip');
        }
    });
})();
```

And this is the error caused to the page when I click the "Recuperar Lista" button:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'close')
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (?view=cards/lista:32:103)

```
                <div align="center" class="popup-cards-from-storage-btns">
                    <input type="button" class="botao botao-mob-100"
                            value="Recuperar Lista"
                            onclick="wizard.updateJsonByLembrarDecisaoOpcional(); wizard.show(); $.modal.close();
                                    analytics.gaTrack('ListaCards - Aceitou lista de cards');"
                            /> 
                            ^^=== THIS IS LINE 32 mentioned in the error above =======

                    <input type="button" class="botao botao-mob-100 botao-preto"
                            value="Ignorar Lista"
                            onclick="wizard.clearLembrarDecisaoOpcional(); wizard.show(); $.modal.close();
                                    analytics.gaTrack('ListaCards - Recusou lista de cards');"
                            />
                </div>
```

Since this is a dynamically generated page, I understand my code may not work because the element is not present when the page is ready, but at the same time, I don't understand why I can't inject code to this page.

Comment: You can use [`waitForKeyElements`](https://gist.github.com/double-beep/c4d4ec3866e5e54ae514c0aab60af242): `waitForKeyElements('.cardtitle', element => { element.title = '...' }, true);`. Also: do you get the error if the userscript is disabled?

Comment: You beat me to it. That is exactly what I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue using the waitForKeyElement() provided by this [library](https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js).

This is how my code looks like now:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var $ = window.jQuery;

    waitForKeyElements (".cardtitle", jNd => $(".cardtitle").prop('title', 'What an awesome tooltip'), true);
})();
```